# What is the best way to ingest embeddings data from multimodalembedding into Vertex AI tabular models

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a set of images that I have created a custom image recognition model that produces a probability in a binary classification that we store in BigQuery as a field. Along with some other tabular data relevant to the image that is also stored in BigQuery, I have created a dataset and trained a tabular model in Vertex AI using the AutoML feature.

I have now added embedding data from the multimodal embedding model - https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/embeddings/get-multimodal-embeddings

The output of this model is a JSON file which I have stored as such within a field in BigQuery.

In terms of creating the new dataset for the Vertex AI pipeline to train a new model to include the embedding data, we currently use a BigQuery SQL query to generate the dataset. Is it best to:

1. Continue to use the SQL query, but use the BigQuery ARRAY data type to represent the JSON embedding data to pass into the dataset for model training. My concern here is that it seems that natively Vertex AI processes ARRAY structure as representing relative weight. In other words, items that appear later in the array are weighted more heavily than items that appear towards the beginning of the array. I am unsure if the embeddings that are generated from multimodalembedding would have similar weighting when it is generated, so in terms of a model learning from the embedding data, the ARRAY structure within BigQuery might remove or minimize any signal that the embedding data has?
2. Create the pipeline to leave the current SQL query to create the dataset as it is and then have the tabular model append the JSON file embedding as a custom transformation and convert the embedding vector into a NumPy array for the tabular model dataset to use. This is a little more complex, but does it mean that the array is treated differently than the above? or does Vertex AI treat all arrays the same way so it wouldnt matter how I did it?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I should add another concern regarding the performance of the tabular model. If the tabular model is sensitive to the order of the features in the JSON file, how do I ensure that the embedding data is processed in the same order every time?